# Jmeter setting for sampler that it should not be in view results tree

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I want that some beanshell samplers of my testplan should not be shown in view results tree. Is that somehow possible?

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 6):

In your case, you can add the below line directly to your script:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore();
```

Then your BeanShell samplers won't show in the view results tree.

Also, for any controller you can add a child JSR223 PostProcessor under it and add the following script:

```
prev.setIgnore();
```

Answer (score 5):

No, It is not possible.

If I want to hide the sampler, I will try to see If I could use `Beanshell preprocessor` or `Beanshell post processor` instead of Beanshell sampler.

Answer (score 2):

Beanshell preprocessor should be used instead of beanshell sampler. 
It doesn't appear in the result tree.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that a pre or post processor is the best solution, but not always viable.

In my case my test plan runs 1 of about 20 random tests each iteration.  Putting a pre or post action on each of these is technically possible, but creates a significant maintenance overhead.  The SampleResult.setIgnore(); solution worked in this case as I only had a single sampler to ignore.